# Couldn't be able to compare four slashes to get a slash in Php regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to print the date to detect the date which is in this format `dd\mm\yyyy` and I have read on stackoverflow that I have to use for slashes to find the `slash` using regex.

so I did this,

```
$dob = "01\01\2014";
preg_match("/\d{2}\\\\\d{2}\\\\\d{4}/",$dob)
```

but it always return `false` when I run it in `if` block, however when I replace the `slash` with `-` like this,

```
$dob = "01-01-2014";
```

and

```
preg_match("/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/",$dob))
```

then it works just fine.

Here is my complete code for the date with back slash,

```
<?php       
    $dob = "01\01\2014";
    $err_msg = "none";
    if (preg_match("/\d{2}\\\\\d{2}\\\\\d{4}/",$dob)){
        $err_msg = "<p>Correct</p>";
    }
    echo $err_msg;
?>
```

and the code that works just fine,

```
<?php       
    $dob = "01-01-2014";
    $err_msg = "none";
    if (preg_match("/\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/",$dob)){
        $err_msg = "<p>Correct</p>";
    }
    echo $err_msg;
?>
```

Comment: Use single quotes for your variable and you'll be fine: `$dob = '01\01\2014';`. Note that your check will identify dates such as `31\99\2015` as correct as well, as you only check the number of digits. Maybe you want to have a look at the [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$dob = "01\\01\\2014";
if (preg_match("/\d{2}\\\\\d{2}\\\\\d{4}/",$dob)) {
   echo "matched\n";
}
```

basically keep `\\`in original variable to get backslashes in variable.

Comment: what if the slashes are forward ?

Comment: also, I only have one slash in `$dob`, not two

Comment: Forward slashes don't need escaping but backslash needs double escaping.

Comment: Yes it is indeed one backslash. when you use `echo $dob;` it will show only one backslash because \\ makes it one backslash in string. `echo "01\01\2014";` will output an invalid set of characters.

Comment: but the value of `$dob` is the user input so the user will always input a single slash not the two, and then i have to replace the single character with the two characters to match the pattern, also, if I try `preg_match("/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}/",$dob)` to match forward slash it doesn't work on php but it matches fine on https://regex101.com

Comment: `$dob = "01/01/2014"; if (preg_match("~\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}~",$dob)) echo "matched";` should work. You cannot use `/` as regex delimiter since it is part of regex pattern also.

Answer (score 2):

```
\d{2}\\\d{2}\\\d{4}
```

You only need `3`.One to escape `\` and one for `d`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/4

Comment: it still doesn't work but the answer of the other guy works. Your answer work in the link you have provided but it is not working in PHP, why is that so ?

Comment: @RileyWillow `$dob` is it exactly same as `"01\01\2014`.Coz the other answer modifies `$dob`

Comment: I get it, but when I try this `preg_match("/\d{2}\\\d{2}\\\d{4}/",$dob)` it doesn't work but this pattern is working in the demo link you provided

Comment: @RileyWillow `"01\01\2014"` here  `\1` is an escape code probably .So this string is getting converted to some other form.The other method is correct

Comment: @RileyWillow the reason why it works on regex101 is coz there `\1` is `\1` not some escape code